# Why is the Query Stream ending before all the asynchronous items are processed when using Node and OracleDB

Tags: node.js, oracle

I have code similar to this....

```
return connection.queryStream(
    config.query,
    params
);
```

Then I have a stream reader

```
class SearchStream{
    constructor(ws, ...){
        this.ws;
        this.stream.on("data", this.onStreamItem.bind(this));
        this.stream.on("error", this.onStreamError.bind(this));
        this.stream.on("end", this.onStreamEnd.bind(this));
    }
    onStremEnd(){
        this.ws.close();
    }
    onStreamItem(item){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.ws.send(...);
        }, 5000)
        // returns promise is real world
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the stream end gets called before the setTimeouts are finished and messages are lost. Can I wait to run Stream End until all the promises are completed?

Comment: What error do you get? Why do you have the `setTimeout` calls? Why would `onStreamItem` return a promise in the "real world"?

Comment: Review the [`selectstream.js`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/selectstream.js#L30) example.   Note we recently updated it to use `destroy()` since this can reduce peak memory usage.